# Beginner advice on how to use FTP or SSH? (django)

Tags: python, django, ftp, web-hosting

I'm in the midst of trying to get my first website up and running all of the sudden I get to the point where I need to get my file online and I have zero idea on how to do that. I thought it would be as easy as selecting your files and clicking upload but so far it has not been that easy. Currently I'm using djangoeurope.com. So if anyone has experience with that site that would help extra.

Comment: Have you tried looking at their support pages for specific info on how to use their site?

Comment: yeah they are VERY lacking it's awful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have ssh access, confirm that it's working by using

```
ssh [username]@[hostname]
```

If you can log in using ssh, you can use scp to put your files onto the server (log out of the remote server first)

```
scp [local_file_path] [hostname]:[remote_file_path]
```

For example,

```
scp local.txt files.server.com:/home/local.txt
```

This should work from a terminal on a Mac or Linux system.  If you're on Windows, you should look at [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/download.php)

Comment: what if this means nothing to me. is there somewhere where i can learn this?/i cant even manage to access the prompt through the site

Comment: which OS are you on? it makes a difference.  If it's Mac or Linux, you can just start the terminal application on your computer and those commands should work.

Comment: Try WinSCP out - it will allow you to connect to your server.  There are quick start instructions at http://winscp.net/eng/docs/getting_started.

Answer (score 0):

If you sign up with Heroku, your deployment process is [very straightforward](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django), and as an added bonus you do not have to deal with FTP and server configuration.

Answer (score 0):

There are different tools for FTP and SSH file transfer. Which one is best for you depends on your environment (e.g. operating system) and your needs (do you want a graphical or command line interface?). But basically it's always a program you run on your machine that connects to a server to upload files. You don't do anything through a web site (except finding out which server to connect to and maybe setting up an account / password).